# Vuetify 2: Pass the additional attributes to item in v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a custom table component based on `v-data-table` (Vuetify 2) element.

I want to add an `id` attribute for each item, to make items work well with e2e-tests.

So instead of

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I want it to render to

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id='[some dynamic id]'>...</tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I found out there's an `item-class` attribute which adds custom classes to each item, but seems like there's no such an easy way for `id`.

I also tried to use the `item` slot to define my own template for items, but is seems like it doesn't work with the custom cells defined via `item.[name]` slot.

Another idea is to modify each item on `mounted` hook with `element.setAttribute('id', <id>)`

Is there another ways?

UPD: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-f9fgdz?file=/src/App.vue) with reproduction

Comment: The easiest way ito add an **id** is to use the index of each record by calling the "key". Other way is to use *prop* or *slot*.

Comment: @Newbee There's no way to pass with _prop_, if I'm correct. It seems to be possible to pass with _slot_, but I don't understand how to do it correctly without affecting all the other data in the table. The way to correctly pass with slot - that is actually what I am looking for, but I cannot find the correct way not to touch an existing modified cells and just pass the id somehow

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't help. But I don't quite understand what your problem really is. What this ```custom column``` for?? if you could give an image or just an static that data that will show the final output you want to achieve maybe I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by changing it from the slot directly like this :

```
<template>
<v-data-table :items="items">
    <template v-slot:item="props">
    <tr :id="'row-' + props.item.id"> <!-- Use a dynamic id -->
        <td>
        <!-- Your custom cell content -->
        <slot name="item.columnName" :item="props.item"></slot>
        </td>
        <!-- ... other columns ... -->
    </tr>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
</template>
```

**OR** ... you can keep the same structure and update it on mounted like this :

```
<template>
<v-data-table :items="items">
    <!-- ... slots for headers and custom cells ... -->
</v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
    items: [
        { id: 1, /* other properties */ },
        { id: 2, /* other properties */ },
        // ... other items ...
    ]
    };
},
mounted() {
    this.items.forEach(item => {
    const rowElement = this.$el.querySelector(`tr[data-item-key="${item[this.itemKey]}"]`);
    if (rowElement) {
        rowElement.setAttribute('id', `row-${item.id}`);
    }
    });
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to render an existing modified columns with your first solution? Though, I created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-f9fgdz?file=/src/App.vue) to play with it

Answer (score 0):

After some time of checking. It is understood that you are trying to make an ID of each record. But, the problem is, there's no `uniques` on each record(so it's difficult to pin point the id of each). If so, we need to create an index of each. Therefore we need to make a function that creates index each of the records. By doing so, I make this sample function to make an `ID` each of the record.

```
<template v-slot:item.bar="{ item }">
    {{
        props2.items
        .map(function (x) {
            return x.bar;
        })
        .indexOf(item.bar) + 1
    }}
</template>
```

[DEMO(forked)](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-9d2g2n?file=/src/App.vue:312-522)

Comment: No, the problem is not to generate an _id_ (or some unique value which has to be used as _id_. The problem is to add it to `<tr>` element without corrupting all the other stuff. 

In fact, I already have such a wrapping table element on my project which is used across all the application and has a lot of customized columns with additional logic. And I want only to add the ids based on the current item-keys to every row on every table.

So the problem is not the generation, but correct forwarding/rendering. 

P.S.: I updated my sandbox to make it more clear